# Differentiate between single and multiple options in react-select onchange using Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-select

When the value of `isMulti` of a react-select is dynamic the type of the parameter to `onchange` is...

```
(parameter) x: MultiValue<{
    value: string | null;
    label: string;
}> | SingleValue<{
    value: string | null;
    label: string;
}>
```

In a handler for this event, how do I handle both cases? i.e. singular and multi?

I tried...

```
onChange={(x) => {
                
   if (typeof x === "MultiValue<{ value: string | null; label string;}")  {

   }
}
```

... and it says...

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" |
> "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" |
> "function"' and '"MultiValue<{ value: string | null; label string;}"'
> have no overlap.ts(2367)

Comment: that's not a discriminated union: which is the discriminating field? moreover, there's no runtime information about the "type", which is a TypeScript compile-time information.

Comment: ok I have removed the tag. yes, that makes sense that that type doesn't exist at runtime. So at runtime, how do I differentiate? isarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultiValue` appears to be just a special name for an array (or array-like).

You can probably just use:

```
if (Array.isArray(x)) {
  // Is MultiValue
} else {
  // Is SingleValue
}
```

And sure enough if we look at the definition...

```
type MultiValue<Option> = readonly Option[];
```

---

Another solution is a type guard:

```
function isMultiValue<T>(arg: MultiValue<T> | SingleValue<T>): arg is MultiValue<T> {
    return Array.isArray(arg);
}
```

It'll narrow down the type to `MultiValue<T>` if possible, otherwise it's `SingleValue<T>`:

```
if (isMultiValue(value)) {
    value
//  ^? // MultiValue<...>
} else {
    value
//  ^? // SingleValue<...>
}
```

[Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQK4BsbAGoEN2oCmANHAMrAB2A5uoXgYXAL5wBmUEIcARFIbgDGMALQBnQnWE8A3AFgAUIoAmhQelz84giJTHwAbviIAuFBiwMiAHgTMAfHAA+5KrXrHCth-KUK2qJTCwLpwwGJomDie1gAq9gAUmtRmkZYx8c6uNHRWXvEAlGbJYWLmUXlxjgiKcHVw-DCoUJRwAIJQULgAngB04R1d3UlQ1AW+zIqKwGxwCeFp0YwJRowFBYi19atEigD0e3UAegD8iqySEpsK9XA7hPuHcKfnQA)

Comment: I got this far and Typescript is happy in the first condition but in the else clause it still thinks that x is the fancy, original type.

Comment: @Ian I updated the answer to include a solution that works for your use case.